# SQL CREATE NEW COLUMN NETWORKDAYS INCLUDING HOLIDAYS

Tags: sql

I need to get the datediff between two dates, and exclude (in the counting), Saturday and Sunday and also Holidays.
I have a table with Holidays, and another table with the rest of the data, and this second table is where the new column will be created.

First off, here is the code:

```
 USE DATABASE
 GO
 alter table [dbo].[TABLE1]
  ADD Loading_LT as (datediff(dd,[OrderDate],[ProcessedDate]))
    - datediff(ww,[OrderDate],[ProcessedDate]) *2
    - (CASE WHEN Datename(dw,[OrderDate]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    - (CASE WHEN Datename(dw,[ProcessedDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(Select Count(*) FROM Holidays Where Holidays >= [OrderDate] AND Holidays < [ProcessedDate])

 GO
```

First, this gives an error because I cannot use a select when creating a new column, now sure if someone can think of a way around it.

Second, I am not even sure that I am looking into this problem in the right direction, this data is extracted via Power BI and Excel. If someone can think if I am using the right approach by creating a new column? Should I use a different technique?
I am super new to SQL so I am treading water on this topic.

Thank you all!

Comment: Have a read of [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and supply sample data with desired results; You should probably consider a *View* for this.

Comment: Thank you @Stu
I am going to ready this right now.

Comment: Are you going to double count holidays that fall on the weekend?

Comment: Rather than a computed column you probably just need to add the column and then update with values.

Comment: It would help to understand what `[dbo].[TABLE1]` contains. For any of these types of problems I suggest you create a calendar table. This is a table with a record per day and a bunch of attributes such as "IsHoliday" and "IsWeekend"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, the table mentioned contains the two columns that holds the data that I want to make the datadiff calc on.
If I create a calendar table, would I be able to create a new column that can calculate the datediff of the fields needed taking into account the calendar table?
I did something similar in Power BI, with a boolean of False if Holiday/Weekend and a True if Workday, and then counted only the True values... but absolutely lost how to do that in SQL.

Comment: @shawnt00 Would I just do the create and then do a type of UPDATE with the information? The information to be populated is the datediff between two dates.
Regarding the "double count holidays that fall on the weekend", no I want to simply count the days that are "work days" in a range of date, this will exclude sat, sun and holidays. There's a *2 that may be the one causing a little noise, that is just multiplying by 2 the value throw by datediff(ww***, because that is giving me the numbers of whole weekends and if there's 1 whole weekend, it means the value to substract is 2, Sat and Sund.

Comment: Yes, if you can create as a nullable column just use `alter table ... add`. I realize what you want to count, but if your holidays table includes weekend dates you'll double count those.

Comment: @shawnt00, Ok I get what you mean with the double problem. 
I guess I have to create the calendar table, add a column there named something as "Workday", flag the Sat and Sund and the holidays as "No", then just take the information from that table, so I don't double count those days.
Really easy in Power BI, but to be honest I have no clue in SQL.
Do you see me having to do some sort of Join to get the info from the "Calendar" Table to match the table with the data I need where the new column will be?
If you can just point me in the direction I can investigate further from there. Thanks!!

Comment: You might just be able to filter those out with `where ... and datepart(weekday, HolidayDate) between 1 and 5`. This would vary with your country though. See `datefirst`

Comment: @shawnt00 Excellent! I have a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: Again I would suggest a calendar table, which is a standard entity in any analytics solution. If you want to proceed with your existing table which has date ranges, then you can use the calendar table to populate it. Or you might find you no longer need your existing table once you have a calendar table. It would help us understand if you posted some sample data and explained what this table is used for.

Comment: I created the calendar table.
Basically, I have a table where there's a person name, the date of an assigned task, and the date of the completed task (each a different column) 
I just need to get the "Lead-Time" that is = CompletedDate - ReceivedDate to get the days it took that person to fulfill its task. For this calculation, I need to exclude the weekends and holidays.
Here is a simplified sample of the data:

`ID OE Arrival Date of PO to OM USERDATE_Loaded
5664 CABRERA, MARTIN 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000`